# find file in path with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I've some file into a dir like this:

```
XXXXX_<start_time>_<end_time>.log
YYYYY_<start_time>_<end_time>.log
ZZZZZ_<start_time>_<end_time>.log
```

I need to write a python script to search files between start_time and end_time given as parameters.

I would try with regex but i'm beginner!
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use regex  for this? It would be easy without. Also you need to at least have tried something, I don't think it is encouraged to just come here and ask for the answer.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: `str.split` with `_` and `.` as separator.

Comment: You'll definitely not want to use regex for this. Also, it's not quite clear what you want. You want to find filenames that contain time ranges that lie entirely inside another, previously defined time range? Can you give some examples that you do/don't want to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex somewhat like this:

```
[A-Z]{5}_(.*)_(.*)\.log
```

Or, you could split by `.`:

```
"XXXXX_<starttime>_<endtime>", "log"
```

Then split the first result by `_` and take the second and third index.

```
"XXXXX", "<starttime>", "<endtime>"
```

Therefore,

```
'XXXXX_<starttime>_<endtime>.log'.split('.')[0].split('_')
```

results in:

```
['XXXXX', '<starttime>', '<endtime>']
```

The second option is definitely easier, but if the format changes (for example `DEFGH<starttime>__<endtime>.log` a regex would be more adaptable.

Comment: i've tried with split fn but i need regex! now i try with your tip! thanks